# Mongoose: findOneAndUpdate not working for multiple conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nestjs

I need to add the new record if the name and likes of employee id not in the array, otherwise need to add a new record.

Ex.

```
{
  name: 'AA',
  likes: [{eid:100},{eid:101}]
},
{
  name:'BB',
  likes:[{eid:100},{eid:102}]
}
```

from API call I'm passing following value

condition 1

---

`{name:'AA', eid: '101'}` => Here the value of `name` "AA" and `eid` 101 both are present in the records so i don't want to add new records

condition 2

---

`{name:'AA', eid: '105'}` => Here new records need to add under the same name so output looks like this

```
    {
      name: 'AA',
      likes: [{eid:100},{eid:101},{eid:105}]
    },
```

condition 3

---

`{name:'CC', eid: '101'}` => then new record should added, so final output is

```
    {
      name: 'AA',
      likes: [{eid:100},{eid:101}, {eid:105}]
    },
    {
      name:'BB',
      likes:[{eid:100},{eid:102}]
    },
    {
      name:'CC',
      likes:[{eid:101}]
    }
```

my code is given below

```
postData(data) {

const newLikeDbDto: LikesDbDto = {
    eid: data.eid
};
await this.feedbackModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        $and:
            [ 
                {
                    $or:
                        [ 
                            { name: data.name, 'likes.eid' :{ $nin: [ data.eid ] } }
                        ]
                },
                {
                    $or: 
                        [
                            { name: data.name }
                        ]
                }
            ]
    },
    {$push: {likes: newLikeDbDto} },
    {new: true, upsert: true})
    .exec()
    
}
```

I'm not expertise in mongoose, so please help me how to achieve these three conditions.

Thanks

Comment: where its your output error? You should use $set, not push

Comment: I need to push the data into the array

Comment: Then dont use find and update, find and update its like find, and then update, you should find and push

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

**Schema**

```
{
    name: { type: String },
    likes: { type: [ { _id: false, eid: { type: Number } } ], default: [] }
}
```

**Sample Records on Collection**

```
[
    {
        name: 'AA',
        likes: [{eid:100},{eid:101}]
    },
    {
        name:'BB',
        likes:[{eid:100},{eid:102}]
    }
]
```

**Condition 1**

```
await FeedbackModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { $or: [ { name:'AA', 'likes.eid': 101 }, { name: 'AA' } ] },
    { $set: { name: 'AA' }, $addToSet: { likes: { eid: 101 } } },
    { upsert: true, new: true }
)
```

**Condition 2**

```
await FeedbackModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { $or: [ { name:'AA', 'likes.eid': 105 }, { name: 'AA' } ] },
    { $set: { name: 'AA' }, $addToSet: { likes: { eid: 105 } } },
    { upsert: true, new: true }
)
```

**Condition 3**

```
await FeedbackModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { $or: [ { name:'CC', 'likes.eid': 101 }, { name: 'CC' } ] },
    { $set: { name: 'CC' }, $addToSet: { likes: { eid: 101 } } },
    { upsert: true, new: true }
)
```